# use angularjs in rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I want use angularjs in a rails project and I'm new to angularjs. for this, I create a `staticpage` controller with `index` action. I set this page for root page:

`config/routes.rb`

```
Restauranteur::Application.routes.draw do
  root "staticpage#index"
end
```

now I download `angular.js` and add to asset pipeline. I remove `turbolink` and add below code to `view/layouts/application.html.erb`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="restauranteur">
<head>
  <title>Restauranteur</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>

<div ng-view>
  <%= yield %>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Then, I create `HomeCtrl.js.coffee`:

```
@restauranteur.controller 'HomeCtrl', ['$scope', ($scope) ->
  # Notice how this controller body is empty
]
```

Now, I set an angular route for show default page, For this I create `main.js.coffee` and create a `templates` directory in public folder.

`main.js.coffee`:

```
@restauranteur = angular.module('restauranteur', [])

@restauranteur.config(['$routeProvider', ($routeProvider) ->
  $routeProvider.
  otherwise({
      templateUrl: '../templates/home.html',
      controller: 'HomeCtrl'
    })
])
```

I create `home.html` in `public/templates` folder.

I want when I run the server,I see `home.html`, but the server run `staticpage/index`, where is the problem? Why `home.html` isn't set as root page and I cannot preview this?

`server log`:

```
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-17 18:54:31 +0430
Processing by StaticpageController#index as HTML
  Rendered staticpage/index.html.erb within layouts/application (0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 12ms (Views: 11.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
Started GET "/assets/staticpage.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-17 18:54:31 +0430
Started GET "/assets/application.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-17 18:54:31 +0430
Started GET "/assets/restaurants.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-17 18:54:31 +0430
Started GET "/assets/scaffolds.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-17 18:54:31 +0430 
Started GET "/assets/jquery.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-17 18:54:31 +0430 
Started GET "/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-17 18:54:31 +0430
Started GET "/assets/angular.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-17 18:54:31 +0430
Started GET "/assets/main.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-17 18:54:31 +0430
Started GET "/assets/angular/controllers/HomeCtrl.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-17 18:54:31 +0430
Started GET "/assets/application.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-17 18:54:31 +0430
```

Note: I use [this tutorial](https://www.honeybadger.io/blog/2013/12/11/beginners-guide-to-angular-js-rails) for do this, but I am not successful.

Answer (score 0):

There are two different layers of views involved in this example:

1. the Rails views
2. the ng-view of AngularJS

I think that 1) is actually working because you see that the application renders `staticpage/index`, just like you specified in the Rails routes.

To get 2) to work, you need to make sure that you include the `main.js` in the `application.js` using the `require_tree .` instruction you see in the tutorial you used.

After this is done, the Angular application will pick up the routes. It will detect that no route matches and executes the `otherwise` section. In your Rails log, you will see that it tries to request the view `templates/home.html`. Once this succeeds, the loaded view will be rendered client-side within the `<div ng-view>` element.

Comment: I edit question and add `server log`. I sure `main.js` and `HomeCtrl.js` are add successfully. I see the log, in server log just rendered `staticpage/index`. now how can I render `public/templates/home.index` instead of `staticpage/index`?

Comment: The rendering as you expect it is done by angular at this point in time, not Rails. I don't see that the template is requested by angular. Please check the browser's javascript console for errors.